# Then is $f_a$ continious?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Excuse me for the bad title, here's the question

> Given a differentiable function defined on R. For a given number $a$, $\forall x\in \mathbb R, x\neq a$, by mean value theorem,  there exists a  $\xi$ between $a$ and $x$ such that $f'(\xi)=\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Suppose it's unique for all $x\neq a$. Therefore $\forall x\neq a$ we define $f_a$ as $f_a(x)=\xi$. Then is $f_a$ continious?

Comment: How can there be a unique number between two unequal real numbers?

Comment: Maybe what you mean is $\forall x \in \mathbb R, x\neq a\,\exists\,\xi$ between $a$ and $x$ such that $f_a(x)=\xi$?

Comment: I'm supposing so

Comment: Is $f_a$ defined at the point $a$? In particular does one need to show that $f_a$ is continous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ or on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{a\}$?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's unique for all $x\neq a$ shouldn't $\xi$ be very very near to $a$? I think it might be continuous on  $\mathbb R\backslash \{a\}$. please answer wondermech question.

Comment: @VladimirVargas wondermech from my question, it's not difficult to see that $f_a$ is defined on $R\{a}$

Comment: @pcx3110: In your example, for $x > 1/2$, we can choose $\xi \in \{-1/2\} \cup [1/2, x)$ arbitrary, so $\xi$ does not seem to be uniqely determined. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PhoemueX I think my example is not an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean value theorem says that for any $x\ne a$, there exists $\xi \in [a,x]$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = f'(\xi).
$$
I believe the question is: if the choice of $\xi$ is unique, then if we define $f_a(x)$ to be that $\xi$ for a given $x$, then is $f_a$ continuous? I also assume that "differentiable" means "the derivative exists and is continouus".

To me it seems that the assumption that the $\xi$ is always unique implies that $f'$ is monotonic. If that's true, then $(f')^{-1}$ exists and is continuous, and we have
$$
f_a(x) = (f')^{-1} \bigg( \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \bigg).
$$
As a composition of continuous functions, this is clearly continuous everywhere except $x=a$. If we further define $f_a(a)=a$, then it matches its limit there and hence is continuous as well.

Can anyone (dis)prove the claim that $f'$ is monotonic under the uniqueness assumption?

Comment: I agree that you've shown that no ray emanating from $(a,f(a))$ can intersect the graph in two other points. What's the proof that this property implies that $f$ is concave (or convex) everywhere?